# Rails collection select only saving part of the attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand how to do a simple thing - save both an id and the text from a collection_select.
I am just beginning work with RoR so I don't have a good grasp on everything yet.
I have experience mostly in Java plus some Perl, so perhaps I did not choose the correct way.

I have a Defect which has a DefectRootCause.
There is another entity, DefaultRootCauses from which I can choose the DefectRootCause.root_cause to associate with a Defect.
I am trying to save the Defect with its DefectRootCause. The DefectRootCause should have the root_cause field as text, the values chosen from the DefaultRootCause.
The problem is that I am only getting to save one of the root_cause or default_root_cause_id for the DefectRootCause.
More, the DefectRootCause.root_cause gets the id form the DefaultRootCause instead of the text.

Please let me know if I am right in trying to get everything to happen "magically" or if I should do some processing of the data in a controller.
See below for the code.

I have the models:

```
class Defect < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :defect_root_cause, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :default_root_cause, :through => :defect_root_cause

end

class DefectRootCause < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :defect
  belongs_to :default_root_cause

end

class DefaultRootCause < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :defect_root_causes
  has_many :defects, :through => :defect_root_causes
end
```

Controller (I only need changes to one of them for this I think):

```
  # POST /defects
  # POST /defects.json
  def create
    #I am doing this because the attributes are not named :defect_root_cause_attribues, I don't know yet why
    @defect = Defect.new(defect_params.except(:defect_root_cause))
    @defect.defect_root_cause = DefectRootCause.new(defect_params[:defect_root_cause])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @defect.save
        format.html { redirect_to @defect, notice: 'Defect was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @defect }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @defect.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
  # PATCH/PUT /defects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /defects/1.json
  def update
        respond_to do |format|
        #I am doing this because the attributes are not named :defect_root_cause_attribues, I don't know yet why
      if @defect.update(defect_params.except(:defect_root_cause)) && @defect.defect_root_cause.update(defect_params[:defect_root_cause])
        format.html { redirect_to @defect, notice: 'Defect was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @defect }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @defect.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def defect_params
        #I am doing this because the attributes are not named :defect_root_cause_attribues, I don't know yet why
      params.require(:defect).permit(:details, defect_root_cause: [:id, :details, :root_cause, :default_root_cause_id])
    end
```

Now the view:

```
<%= form_for @defect do |f| %>
  <% if @defect.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@defect.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this defect from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @defect.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :details %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :details %>
    <%= f.fields_for @defect.defect_root_cause do |drc| %>
    <%= drc.label :root_cause%>
    <%= drc.collection_select(:default_root_cause_id, DefaultRootCause.all, :id, :root_cause, :prompt => true) %>

    <%= drc.label :details%>
    <%= drc.text_field :details %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
      <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the routes.rb I only have the following:

```
  resources :default_root_causes
  resources :defects
  resources :defect_root_causes

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'defects#index'
```

Finally, my problem (root_cause is nil):

```
irb(main):006:0> DefectRootCause.find(10)
  DefectRootCause Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `defect_root_causes`.* FROM `defect_root_causes` WHERE `defect_root_causes`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
=> #<DefectRootCause id: 10, details: "sadsad", defect_id: 9, default_root_cause_id: 2, created_at: "2016-02-19 05:52:06", updated_at: "2016-02-19 05:52:06", root_cause: nil>
```

if I change the select to:

```
<%= drc.collection_select(:root_cause, DefaultRootCause.all, :id, :root_cause, :prompt => true) %>
```

I get the following (root_cause is saved but it is a number not the text - in this case I want the following text: "second root cause", plus the default_root_cause_id is nil):

```
irb(main):005:0> DefectRootCause.find(9)
  DefectRootCause Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `defect_root_causes`.* FROM `defect_root_causes` WHERE `defect_root_causes`.`id` = 9 LIMIT 1
=> #<DefectRootCause id: 9, details: "das", defect_id: 8, default_root_cause_id: nil, created_at: "2016-02-19 05:42:36", updated_at: "2016-02-19 05:42:36", root_cause: "2">
```

EDIT:

Now I am posting what I have done to save all the information where I need it.
I am now posting as an answer because I still don't know if this is the right way of doing this.
So please, if you know it should be done differently let me know. I am looking especially at how to send all the information from the view. I saw the view "knows" both the id and the text of the selected DefaultRootCause, but I don't get both in the params sent.

So, now the code.

View:

```
<%= drc.select :default_root_cause_id, DefaultRootCause.all.collect{|r| [r.root_cause, r.id]}, :prompt => true %>

defects_controller.rb
def create
@defect = Defect.new(defect_params.except(:defect_root_cause))
@defect.defect_root_cause = DefectRootCause.create(defect_params[:defect_root_cause].merge(:root_cause => DefaultRootCause.find(defect_params[:defect_root_cause][:default_root_cause_id]).root_cause))
respond_to do |format|........
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @defect.update(defect_params.except(:defect_root_cause)) && @defect.defect_root_cause.update(defect_params[:defect_root_cause].merge(:root_cause => DefaultRootCause.find(defect_params[:defect_root_cause][:default_root_cause_id])))
```

With those I get the following params and also the following inserts:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jGUQIxeXWZwg5lqsPFrE4vO9z4ioRnAN/Z1/K9scQiIeQ0MTHBTvZoDcwHKtGvrgrG53y4yr7tX4wnCShoZ/oA==", "defect"=>{"details"=>"a", "defect_root_cause"=>{"default_root_cause_id"=>"2", "details"=>"a"}}, "commit"=>"Create Defect"}
  DefaultRootCause Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `default_root_causes`.* FROM `default_root_causes` WHERE `default_root_causes`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `default_root_causes`.* FROM `default_root_causes` WHERE `default_root_causes`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `default_root_causes`.* FROM `default_root_causes` WHERE `default_root_causes`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `defect_root_causes` (`details`, `default_root_cause_id`, **`root_cause`**, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('a', 2, **'second root cause'**, '2016-02-23 07:10:59', '2016-02-23 07:10:59')
```

Now, please let me know if this is "the right" way to do this.

Thank you,
Victor

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update an associated attributes through the parent which means you need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Add this method to your `Defect` model like so:

class Defect < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :defect_root_cause, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :default_root_cause, :through => :defect_root_cause

accepts_nested_attributes_for :defect_root_cause
end

After doing that, go to your `defects_controller.rb` and update the `#defect_params` method to:

`params.require(:defect).permit(:details, defect_root_cause_attributes: [:id, :details, :root_cause, :default_root_cause_id])`

Comment: Hi, I tried before with the accepts_nested... did not work. Tried again now, still not working. I have the .permit part but it is not with defect_root_cause_attributes because I don't know why they are sent as defect_root_cause, not as defect_root_cause_attributes...

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use the following code:

```
<%=f.select :default_root_cause_id,  DefaultRootCause.all.collect{|r| [r.route_cause,"#{r.route_cause} - #{r.id}"]} %>
```

Comment: Hi, when I try this I am getting the following parameters sent: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Q4VOGRvnru4jP3oFtPTdPqEG8qsvzK9xAe/hbYWm+AQuAxt9hOk62xrcBzGaKiuGR7LB7HpTq8NFAcY373jiRg==", "defect"=>{"details"=>"gigi", "defect_root_cause"=>{"default_root_cause_id"=>"second root cause - 2", "details"=>"gigi"}}, "commit"=>"Create Defect"} .                  I get the following error: Mysql2::Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testRailsAPP_development`.`defect_root_causes`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_97daa073d4` FOREIGN KEY (`default_root_cause_id`)

Comment: @Victors Can you tell me what is the data type of your column default_root_cause_id

Comment: Hi, I will do it later as now I am at work. In this case it tries to save a DefaultRootCause.default_root_cause_id =0 (instead of 2) and that does not exist. I can make this work in the controllers - I get the text from the DefaultRootCause.root_cause based on the default_root_cause_id I am getting sent, but I don't know if this is the right way of doing it. I have a version where I get all the relationships saved but with the "translation" done in the controller. I was expecting to get everything in place using the default behavior of RoR.

Comment: Sorry for being late with this. t.integer  "default_root_cause_id", limit: 4 I think this can be solved by doing something in the controller, I just don't know if this is the right way of doing it. Will post the code which makes this work after I make it work :).